# SPF pass on Google and fail on Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, dns, gmail, spf

My website has problem to send email. They go on trash on Outlook, but not on Gmail.

I configured my DNS with this : DOMAINNAME. IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:IP -all"

where DOMAINNAME is my domain name, IP is the server's ip.

This is what I get from emails :

- Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of commerciale@DOMAINNAME designates IP as permitted sender)
- Received-SPF: fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of DOMAINNAME does not designates IP as permitted sender)

I've 2 questions :

- Why does it work on Google and not on Outlook ?
- Why Google pass the domain : commerciale@DOMAINNAME and Outlook the domain DOMAINNAME (without commerciale) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SPF record is empty. You need to include hosts and IP addresses, or even IP address blocks (in *cidr notation*) you want to authorize to send email on behalf of your domain name.

1. Make a list of all the places from which you send email: operational email (day-to-day email) hosting, transactional emails, email marketing, etc.
2. Add the includes and/or IP addresses to your SPF record. Note: You *very* rarely need the +a +mx stuff. It's redundant. The MX will just increase DNS overhead by triggering another round of lookups.
3. Validate your SPF record using a tool such as the [SPF Survey](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/)

Here's an example SPF record that assumes G Suite for email hosting, MailChimp, and an IP address.

`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net ip4:192.0.2.20 ~all`

Note: I terminated this example with `~all` (softfail), which is considered the best practice.

Then I'd recommend implementing DKIM signing with all email sources. Then implement DMARC using a service like dmarcian.com (they have a free tier) to make reading the DMARC reports way easier. DMARC gives you a view into your email streams.

Comment: @Destunk No problem!

Comment: Btw, when you look at headers after adding things explicitly to your SPF does it now _Pass_ in outlook, Gmail?

Comment: I cannot see how this answered the question of why did it pass on Google?